# A Web Component is the only technology to create framework-agnostic components. Or is there any alternative?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have build a JavaScript toolkit in Angular which contains a lot of 'basic' components, like buttons and fields. For a new project, I am doing some research for a more framework-agnostic way to implement such components, so I can reuse my components in other JavaScript frameworks as well.

During my research I found just one alternative: web components, using custom elements. According to so many resources and blogs a web component is the best and only way to create a framework-agnostic component. How can I considering a new technology if there is just one? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web Component API, as far as I know, is the only built in framework for Web Components.

There are plenty of other frameworks for making components but those normally come with **lots** of extras that have nothing to do with components.

I had a system I wrote years ago that was **just** for creating a component and nothing else. But it was very limited and I have since moved to Web Components for everything.

Writing a true, native Web Component allows you to reuse that code in any and all frameworks. I have some components that have been used, without change in Vanilla JS, AngularJS, Angular, VUE and React.

There are issues with a shadowDOM element and styling between projects but that is small compared to being able to reuse all of your components when your company insist on changing frameworks.